# iOS Swift2 recording preparation may create empty/unused files

Tags: ios, swift2, record, avaudiorecorder

### Overview

I found a lag after hitting my "Record" button, so I came up with a solution which causes other problems. My solution is to prepare the audio recorder very often, but this will always create an empty file, which sometimes is never recorded to. NOTE that this only happens on a physical device, not in simulation.

### Questions

Is there a way to either (1) reduce the lag when recording a file without creating empty files or (2) efficiently clean up non-recorded files? It seems that (2) should be run every time the app or view loads.

### Code

Part 0: my variables

```
var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
var currentAudioFilename = "" // the file to play
var nextAudioFilename = "" // the file to record
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
```

Part 1: my setupRecorder()

```
do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
            nextAudioFilename = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".wav"
            try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.directoryURL(nextAudioFilename)!,
                                                settings: recordSettings)
}
catch {}
audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
audioRecorder.delegate = self
print("Recorder setup with new name: current-" + currentAudioFilename + " next-" + nextAudioFilename + " forceSetup-\(forceSetup)")
```

Part 2:

```
// set player's filename to recorder's filename
currentAudioFilename = nextAudioFilename

if !audioRecorder.recording {
    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        audioRecorder.record()}
        catch {print("could activate the recorder")
    }
}
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: My solution has been to prepare the audio recorder after any audio play event and at page load. I have stored the next file in Defaults so that I can only have one empty file at a time.